# Django auto repost data a week, month or a year depending on it's frequency of recurrence

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

In my django project I am trying to repost a record based on its frequency of recurrence which could be daily, weekly, monthly etc. Let's say a record is posted today and it's frequency of recurrence is weekly, I want the record to keep reappearing on a weekly basis on the 'day' and 'time' as the previous week when it was created and so on, that is, an old record will be new and top of other records which will now be older than it based on frequency of recurrence.

models.py

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    none = 0
    Daily = 1
    Weekly = 7
    Monthly = 30
    Quarterly = 90
    SemiAnual = 180
    Yearly = 365

    Frequency_Of_Reocurrence = (
        (none, "None"),
        (Daily, "Daily"),
        (Weekly, "Weekly"),
        (Monthly, "Monthly"),
        (Quarterly, "After 3 Months"),
        (SemiAnual, "After 6 Months"),
        (Yearly, "After 12 Months")
    )
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="food name", null=False, blank=False, max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Food Description", max_length=350, null=False, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path, default='veggies.jpg')
    isrecurring = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    frequencyofreocurrence = models.IntegerField(choices=Frequency_Of_Recurrence)
    datetimecreated = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date-time-created', auto_now_add=True)
```

How exactly can I achieve what I'm trying to do in my views.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

## a little bit complication to solve it:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, F, ExpressionWrapper
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate, Mod, Now
qset = Menu.objects.exclude(Frequency_Of_Reocurrence = 0)
    .annotate(duration = ExpressionWrapper(
        (TruncDate(Now())-TruncDate('datetimecreated'))/F('Frequency_Of_Reocurrence'),
        output_field = IntegerField())
    .annotate(reorder = ExpressionWrapper(Mod('duration', 10**8), output_field=IntegerField()))
    .filter(reorder = 0).order_by('datetimecreated').values()
```

## maybe you can refine the code.

Comment: I got an `'ExpressionWrapper' object has no attribute 'filter'` error

Comment: the second annotate need append one more ")"

Comment: resolved that. I am looking at the code and I don't get this line `Mod('duration', 10**8)`, why divide duration by 10 ** 8?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up a cron job to check on a daily basis, have conditions to determine if a particular record is due for repost then repost that (update the time stamp if you’re not looking to create a new record). I don’t write Django so I can’t give specifics.